# Probability - Screening off/ Casuality

Tags: probability, statistics, causality

> Let   ,   , and    be events. If  $(|∩)=(|)$ , then    is said to screen    off from   . Suppose that  $(∩)>0$.  Show that screening off is equivalent to saying that  $$(∩|)=(|)(|).$$  What does this latter equation say in terms of independence?

1. I am struggling to find a way to formulate an answer to this.

   Essentially what I am thinking is something along the lines of:

   As
   $$ 
      P(E|C) = \frac{P(E∩C)}{ P(C)}
   $$
   And
   $$
      P(A∩C) = P(A|C)P(C)
   $$
   Then something along the lines of:
   $$
      \frac{P(E∩(P(A∩C)P(C))) }{P(A∩C)P(C)} = \frac{P(E∩C) }{P(C)}
   $$

   That is a very rough idea. I am not sure if that is even remotely close to what I need to be doing. Any suggestions would be great. Ideally I would like to figure this out myself but a nudge in the right direction would be great.
2. The later equation indicates that event E and A are independent of one another as knowing the outcome of event A does not interfere with the outcome of event E.

Comment: 1. The questions specifies that E and C are not mutually exclusive, but I don't see why this condition is necessary. $\quad$  2. "*What does this latter equation say in terms of independence?*" The latter equation says that A is conditionally independent of E, given C.

Comment: @ryang For the best explanation possible. Check out this section [ScreeningOff](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-probabilistic/#ScreOff)      Section 2.2) Screening Off Prior to finding this article, I roughly understood how it was used but I am not quite confident enough to explain it to the level they are capable of.

Comment: @ryang Initially yes as a rough example to see if I was heading in the right direction but after revising and the assistance from the gentleman below I realised that was not meant to be the case. I was under the impression I needed to substitute for both sides when in actual fact just the one would have sufficed. This is the first example of this I have ever had to work with. It is apart of a homework assignment. We have not learnt about Screening off and I could not seem to find any examples in the section of the textbook/ lectures we have covered as of yet hence the reason I asked.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. To be super clear: I think that the given condition $\quad$ "Suppose that $P(E∩C)>0$" $\quad$ is **redundant**, because *even if* $P(E∩C)=0,$ the required result $P(A∩E|C)=P(A|C)P(E|C)$ *still holds*.

Comment: @ryang Oh that statement is what you are referring too. That makes more sense now. That is not a claim of mine, it is their question. I don't know why they felt the need to include it as long as P(C) ≠ 0 Then the theory of causality will hold. I do agree with you on that, they have a weird way of wording their questions sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is close. Applying the definition of conditional probability,

$$\begin{align*}
P(E\mid A\cap C) &= P(E\mid C)\\
\frac{P(E\cap A \cap C)}{P(A\cap C)} &= P(E\mid C)\\
\frac{P(A\cap E\mid C)P(C)}{P(A\mid C)P(C)} &= P(E\mid C)\\
P(A\cap E\mid C) &= P(A\mid C)P(E\mid C)
\end{align*}$$

---

Compare these, with or without condition:

$$\begin{align*}
P(E\mid A\cap C) &= \frac{P(E\cap A\mid C)}{P(A\mid C)} &&(P(C)\ne 0)\\
P(E\mid A) &= \frac{P(E\cap A)}{P(A)}
\end{align*}$$

Compare these, for 1) independent $A$ and $E$ given $C$, and 2) independent $X$ and $Y$:

$$\begin{align*}
P(A \cap E\mid C) &= P(A\mid C)P(E\mid C)\\
P(X\cap Y) &= P(X)P(Y)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!